How to capture live terminal test session at runtime as generated on terminal
while running a test, I want to save all the terminal live logs into log or txt file like below,
Expected output:
================================================================== test session starts ===================================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.9.9, pytest-8.2.2, pluggy-1.5.0
rootdir: C:..........\PycharmProjects\PytestProject1
configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: html-4.1.1, metadata-3.1.1, sugar-1.0.0, tap-3.4
collected 1 item
test_demo1.py
.
[100%]
=================================================================== 1 passed in 0.04s ====================================================================
is it fine if we can use any python plugin.

does this SO QA solve your problem?

You can run pytest by redirecting its output to a file from command line.
pytest > console_logs.log 2>&1
